# C#/WPF - Picturebox like control?

Tags: c#, wpf

Does a picturebox like control exist in WPF? I want a control that I can easily change/retrieve the backcolor of.

Answer (score 3):

`Image` is the class you are looking for. The name may be confusing, but it is a control. Also, everything in WPF can be customized. The background color of every control can be changed.

Comment: How do I change the backcolor of an image? I basically want the Image control to only display a color.

Comment: Well in this case just use a `Grid` and set the `Background` to the color you want

Comment: Are there any other alternatives to Grids? I need to add a lot and Grids get placed weirdly.

Comment: Then you should reformat your question, stating what you need, what you've tried and what doesn't work!

Comment: I'm trying to dynamically add items to a DockPanel. Dynamically adding a 'colored grid' to the DockPanel makes it align in the center-left, but I want it at the top-left.

Answer (score -2):

You can use rectangle control & set the Fill property with the respective color.
For click event, you can add MouseDownEvent handler to rectangle.